# What is the best format to use when writing out dates? 

Tags: writing, dates

What format of date is appropriate for different contexts (business, personal) in written English, nowadays?

- 1st of April, 2010
- April the 1st, 2010
- April 1, 2010
- April 01, 2010
- another one

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The context that matters most is where you are located geographically (or which variety of English you otherwise wish to employ).

Paul covered the case of the US: "April 1, 2010". That would surely be understood in the UK too, but to my knowledge "1 April 2010" (NB: no comma) or "1/4/2010" would be more common there.

**Edit**: Based on some quick "research" I just did, most commonwealth countries (Australia, New Zealand, South Africa) also seem to prefer "1 April 2010", while in Canada "April 1, 2010" would be more common (probably due to US influence).

As Paul mentioned, YYYY-MM-DD is pretty good for getting across universally, yet concisely. In my opinion the format often used by airlines – "01 Apr 2010" – is useful too; there isn't much room for misinterpretation there.

Comment: Please comment and correct me if I'm wrong about preferred usage in some of the countries I mentioned.

Comment: And if someone knows of situations where some longer form (e.g. "the first of April, 2010") would be the most preferable, please tell!

Comment: All branches of the American military use the Commonwealthy order: 1 April 2010.

Comment: Longer forms, spelling out "first", would generally be used only on wedding invitations, in my experience.

Comment: And as Pavel pointed out, YYYY-MM-DD has the additional benefit of being designated as an [international standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 23):

In the United States, it is customary to write "April 1, 2010", regardless of context. This is spoken, however, as "April first, 2010".

I would discourage using MM/DD/YYYY (e.g. 4/1/2010) format, because this may cause confusion as the rest of the world writes the day before the month. If you really need to write dates in a consise format, I recommend YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: +1 for YYYY-MM-DD format, which has the additional benefit of automatically sorting into chronological order when sorted  alphanumerically by computers.

Comment: I'll use "1 Apr 2010" in software that is trying to be concise but user friendly. I jus think it the most easy to read, unambiguous format across the greatest range of people (English speakers at least). I'll use "2010-04-01" or even "20100401" in the more machine only side of software or where sorting can be important, such as file names.

Comment: Also the unit flow descends correctly when used in conjunction with a time stamp YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF = 2012-12-31 23:34:53.324

Comment: I normally spell the Month explicitly using its full name or its three letter abbreviation, like "4-Apr-2013" or "4-April-2013" (possibly with different punctuation), and notate the year using 4 digits. This removes most ambiguity. I find the YYYY-MM-DD format reader-unfriendly because people are not used to starting with the year.

Answer (score 12):

There's now an international standard of date format, aka [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) - so if you care about making the world a better and less confusing place, you should only use the standard - YYYY-MM-DD, forever dropping the old local date format ideas.

Comment: I reject the assumption that more standardization amounts to improvement.

Comment: @Animadversor – any clever normalization of date format is good to revert current [chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country), also pointing to the fact that relatively least logical date format *April 1, 2010* is used only by minority of the population, see the population numbers in the linked article.

Answer (score 4):

I always write the month as either "Apr" or "April" and the year like 2010 to avoid any confusions. For example,

```
01/04/10
```

is way too ambiguous.

```
1 Apr 2010
```

is much clearer. Personally I prefer

```
2010-04-01
```

but I realize that this is because I am a geek, i.e. the chances of this format being accepted generally are pretty slim.

Comment: The chances of 2010-04-01 being "accepted generally" is pretty high (100% probability is high, isn't it?) ... in Hungary. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually go for 1st April 2010.

(That's [`jS F Y`](http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).)

Comment: I would normally use this.  Most people are dropping out the ordinal but I think it looks much better.  I would speak it as "the first of April" but wouldn't normally write the "the" or "of".

Comment: Not only does it make good sense to use YYYY-MM-DD, but if you must sort information on the date, it is much better.

Comment: @LindaLawson-Bruton. In the absence of further clarification, I'm assuming that this question is referring to dates in running text, not in filenames. In database fields, it should be stored as a date object, however the database chooses to store that internally, and represented however seems appropriate to the viewer.