# How should a date be written?

Tags: writing, dates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Date formatting in written English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420/date-formatting-in-written-english)

Which of these is the correct way to write a date?

1- Wednesday 5th of June, 2010
2- Wednesday 5th June, 2010
3- Wednesday the 5th of June, 2010

Answer (score 5):

I have most often seen "Wednesday, June 5, 2010", when the day of the week is included.

Usually, though, the day of the week is not included in the date; hence:

> June 5, 2010 (for general U.S. and Canada usage)
>
> 5 June 2010 (for general U.K. and related usage)

The preceding examples pertain mainly to non-technical usage.  For technical or more rigorous usages, you should use a numeric format (e.g. 2010-06-05 or 06-05-2010).  If you do use a numeric format, be sure that the numeric format is compatible with the situation you use it in; if you're not careful, you might accidentally switch MM with DD.

For further information, reference [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420/date-formatting-in-written-english).

Comment: Note that 2010-06-05 is not ambiguous (as far as I know), whereas 06-05-2010 is (as per the US/UK distinction you've already highlighted).

Comment: @Ben Good point!

Comment: @Ben: excellent point, that has annoyed me since the end of time.  2010.06.05 is my way, but it seems rather technical and peculiar to most readers...

Comment: it's an infinite loop.  there is no end?  this is probably a physics question :)

Answer (score 1):

As @drm65 has pointed out, there are various international standards, and it's not common to include the day of the week.  However, there is one important exception: formal event announcements.  It's quite customary to include the day of the week in a wedding invitation, for instance.  (I can only speak for American customs, of course; British invitations might be in binary for all I know.)  Here are a few valid formats:

Spelling out all numbers - quite formal, and a little unnatural:
  **Wednesday, the fifth of June, two thousand ten, at four o'clock in the afternoon.**

All numbers in digits - much less formal; maybe *too* informal to be quite natural:
  **Wednesday June 5, 2010 at 4 p.m.**

Compromise:
  **Wednesday, June fifth, 2010, at four o'clock in the afternoon**

There are other possibilities, of course.  In general, you can use "June 5th", "June fifth", or "the fifth of June"; "the 5th of June" and "June the fifth" look a little strange; don't use "fifth June".

I personally like and use "5 June 2010" (back when I used to write actual paper checks, that was my preferred format), but I wouldn't put it on an invitation.