# Twenty-Fifth or 25th?

Tags: dates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best format to use when writing out dates?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420/what-is-the-best-format-to-use-when-writing-out-dates)

In represent a time and date, which of the following is the most proper (did I even frame this question right?)

> Tuesday, September 25, 2012

vs

> Tuesday, September 25th, 2012

vs

> Tuesday, September Twenty-Fifth, 2012

For whatever reason, this has sparked debate where I work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't a question of any of them being proper. Different people follow different conventions. The important thing is that those working in any one organisation decide on a particular format and stick to it. My own practice, following the practice where I once worked, is to write *25 September 2012*, putting the day of the week in front only if necessary. That seems to me to be clear and simple.

Answer (score -1):

The first two are interchangeable and are a matter of style. "Twenty-Fifth" would look strange outside of an extremely formal setting like a wedding invitation.