# Location of day of week in non-U.S. long format dates?

Tags: writing, dates

In the United States, the long/expanded/full form of a date with day of the week is:

Monday, February 24, 2014

I understand in other countries the long date form is often:

24 February 2014

So where does the day of week go with this format and is there a comma between the month day and day of week?

Comment: Could you make clearer how this is an English language and usage question and why a general reference does not address this?

Comment: @virmaior: point me to the general reference that covers this and I will be on my way.  Searching I have come across countless examples of `day month year` vs `month day, year` but not discussing day of week.

Comment: @virmaior: I fail to see how my question is qualitatively different from: [What is the best format to use when writing out dates?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420/what-is-the-best-format-to-use-when-writing-out-dates)

Comment: It looks like day of week is not generally included in British format. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Date_and_time_representation_by_country

Comment: @virmaior: hence my question as surely they must use it sometimes

Answer (score 2):

It would also be at the beginning: Monday, 24 February 2014. I don't have a reference for you, but if you read enough BBC news articles, you'll come across it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The 7th bullet here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendar_date#Gregorian.2C_day-month-year_.28DMY.29

"Sunday, 8 November 2003"