# How would I punctuate Sunday, November 19 6:30 to 7:30 PM

Tags: time, dates

How would I punctuate Sunday, November 19 6:30 to 7:30 PM when giving the date and start/end time of an event?

Comment: I would rearrange it to read "Sunday, 19 November from 6:30pm to 7:30pm". Separating the numerals helps to make it clearer, but it's really a matter of style and personal preference. I'll see what the Oxford Manual of Style says when I've got a spare moment (assuming that the question isn't closed for being off-topic).

Comment: Thank you, This is on our calendar of events and it looks odd the way it is listed. I thought it should have some punctuation. Usually only the start time is listed after the date with no punctuation. With this listing I was asked to list both times and it looked odd. The space is limited so I try to limit verbiage. Thank you for your help... If you do find something let me know and no rush...

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. There are dozens of possible ways of writing and punctuating dates and times—regional differences, differences between style guides, etc. There is no one correct way.

Comment: I would suggest a nap.

Comment: The question that this one is said to duplicate doesn't ask about a date form that includes the day of the week or a specific hour or hour range. Consequently, I don't think that this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

According to [dalywritingtips.com](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/how-to-punctuate-references-to-dates-and-times/), there are two possibilities:

> The meeting is scheduled for Wednesday, August 31, 7-9 p.m.

or

> The meeting is scheduled for Wednesday, August 31, from 7 to 9 p.m.

You can also find more information in [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dates), and also  [in this site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_the_United_States) and [in this other site](http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/how-to-write-dates-british-american-english/). Oh, and don't forget to check the question [*What is the best format to use when writing out dates?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420/what-is-the-best-format-to-use-when-writing-out-dates)

Comment: Upvoted because you included source links and offered a succinct and reasonable discussion of the subject. I would add only that the form "August 31" seems more heavily preferred in U.S. English than in UK English, where "31 August" has considerable support.

Comment: Thank you, Sven. Yes, it is an en dash. The source says "Print publications should use an en dash for the time range; some online publications do so, too." There is some variation between U.S. English and UK English, but the question does not elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

In American English, the correct format is:

**Sunday, November 19, from 6:30 to 9:30 PM**

(PM could alternatively be written p.m.)

If you prefer, you can shorten it by replacing from/to with an en-dash.

**Sunday, November 19, 6:30–9:30 PM**

Comment: It looks good, but why is it "correct"? Is this from a style guide, e.g. the Chicago Manual of Style? (not that style guides are infallible,) or is it some federal standard?